# What does it mean for a hearing that has been listed to be “vacated”?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, any-jurisdiction

Does it more strongly suggest that it will have been dispensed with finally, or that it will be rescheduled/relisted for another date?

Comment: I’ve reviewed several similar questions but don’t find this one adequately or at all answered by their comments and answers.

Comment: I’m not sure If even the questions are somewhat different. I’m asking about a hearing date being vacated, they’re asking about an entire case being so. I think these might imply different senses of the word.

Comment: I’ve done my best to consolidate the two into that one but then realised that’s not a solution because I have no control over the asker having  accepted what I regard as an inadequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean for a trial, or other hearing, that has been listed to be “vacated”?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6535/what-does-it-mean-for-a-trial-or-other-hearing-that-has-been-listed-to-be-vac)